# pip install -e vs without in terms of preformance

Tags: python, pip, python-poetry, pythoninterpreter

I develop some dependencies locally and I have a dep_requirements.txt file that looks like this:

```
-e path_to_dependency_1
-e path_to_dependency_2
-e path_to_dependency_3
```

Is it ok to leave it that way for production when building the production docker? Or I should remove the -e because it prevents Python caching, "compiling" or something else?

I'm basically asking, is `-e` (editable) problematic to use in production environment? will it harm performance

Comment: It likely won't harm, I suppose, but I'd never do this in production build where we expect dependency management to be as fool-proof and mature is possible. We need editable installs to achieve, uhm, editable installs - if you don't need to edit code within your production docker container (I hope you don't do this), you don't need editable install, it's unnecessary complication and tool used for wrong goal.